# Show that $y^n = x^2 + a$ has no solutions.

Tags: number-theory

Let $p \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ be prime and denote $n := \frac{p − 1}{2} \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a − 1, a, \text{and } a + 1$ are all quadratic residues modulo $p$.

Show that $y^n = x^2 + a$ has no solutions.

My thoughts:

i thought about using a few facts and trying to combine them. For example:

1) $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod p$

2) $a$ is a quadratic residu modulo $p$, so $x^2 = a \pmod{p}$ has a solution.

I don't see how to combine these thoughts to prove this. I tried looking at modulo $p$, so we see:

$y ^ n \pmod{p} \equiv x^2 + a \pmod {p} \equiv \dots$.

What do i want to get at the dots for a contradiction is solutions?

Kees

Comment: In your statement you say " Suppose that $a\in \mathbb Z$ such that $a−1,a$, and $a+1$ are all quadratic residues modulo $p$"  Did you mean "are NOT quadratic residues modulo $p$?

Comment: no they are quadratic residues, i mixed up at statement 2 but edited it right away thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also assume $a-1,a,a+1\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ in order for this to be true. Let $a+1\equiv b^2\pmod{p},$ $a\equiv c^2\pmod{p}$, $a-1\equiv d^2\pmod{p}$ (it's given that such $b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$ exist).

By Fermat's Little theorem $y^{p-1}\equiv \{0,1\}\pmod{p}$, so $y^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \{-1,0,1\}\pmod{p}$.

So it's sufficient to prove none of the congruences $x^2\equiv -(a+1)\pmod{p}$, $x^2\equiv -a\pmod{p}$, $x^2\equiv -(a-1)\pmod{p}$ has a solution.

I.e. none of the congruences $\left(xb^{-1}\right)^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, $\left(xc^{-1}\right)\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, $\left(xd^{-1}\right)^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution.

This is clear, because $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=-1$, because $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ ([quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.E2.88.921_and_the_first_supplement)).

Comment: I don't see how you get the $0$ with fermat's little theorem, isn't that supposed to be a $1$ only?

Comment: @KeesTil Fermat's Little theorem claims that if $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. If $a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Comment: thanks, one last question: arent the inverses at the congruences supposed to be a ^$-\frac{1}{2}$ instead of ^$-1$?

Comment: @KeesTil Indeed, I've edited it, although without the $^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ notation, which I've never seen used for modular square roots.